# NiFi-Registry and Git Integration: Git User configuration and authentication

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

I have setup Secured Nifi on 2 servers and started version control using secured nifi-registry.
Now for pushing bucket changes to Git, I have edited nifi-registry 'providers.xml' as described in nifi-registry admin-guide.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-registry-docs/html/administration-guide.html#flow-persistence-providers

And when I am starting versioning for a flow, it is getting saved in directory under Nifi-registry dir(which is created after I cloned repository) but the flow is not getting pushed to  Git repository.
Not sure if any Git user configuration and authentication is required.
Can anyone please help in setting this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out load things, able to push directly into Git.
In `conf/providers.xml` file of NiFi-Registry, have to add 1 more below property under **flowPersistenceProvider**:

```
<property name="Commit To Push">master</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

have tried this as a cluster setup. If so looking for some input on upgrading the registry image.